# Fluent NHibernate Cascade Delete when Tables Have No Relationship

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Is there a way (in Fluent NHibernate) to cascade delete from tables which have no direct relationship with each other? I have the situation below:

[image: Relationship Diagram]

What I would *like* to happen is for Authorizations to be cascade deleted when a CustomerProduct is deleted (where auth.Customer = cp.Customer and auth.Product = cp.Product).

Authorization did have a direct relationship with CustomerProduct up until recently but it's been broken away from that so I can't solve the issue that way.

I was hoping to do something like (from CustomerProduct mappings):

```
        mapping.HasMany<Authorization>(x => x.Authorizations)
            .KeyColumn("ProductID")
            .KeyColumn("CustomerID")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

But obviously that's not going to work as there's no Authorizations member in CustomerProduct (at least I think that's why it doesn't work ^^).

Comment: This should be solved in the business layer, since there is a piece of business logic that knows how to remove the relation of a customer to a product.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger Are you saying I should be managing this in my CustomerProductController (I'm working in asp.Net MVC) rather than in the mappings? That I can certainly do but I was hesitant to as I don't see any other examples of the Controllers messing with entities that aren't in their direct purview...

Comment: A controller may send event when creating / changing or deleting something and another controller may clean up its own stuff.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger Thanks for the clarification, as you can tell I'm pretty green! Your comment put me onto the track of some useful reading, thanks again.

Comment: green or not, this are the kind of problems where every developer is actually fighting with, in every project again. Dependencies between domains ... It's one of those "there-is-no-silver-bullet" problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be solved in the business layer, since there is a piece of business logic that knows how to remove the relation of a customer to a product.